# Integrate JavaScript project to an existing ReactJS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, bower

I want to integrate this repo to my existing react.js project https://github.com/zoltan-dulac/Matrix-Construction-Set
. The `Matrix-Construction-Set` project has lots of `Javascript` files and some `bower` packages that are required to be present for it to work properly. I have installed bower and I have all packages under `/bower_components` that is at the same level as `/node_modules`. In the `Matrix-Construction-Set` project, all `js` files are included as `<script/>` after `<body/>` tag. I am using a custom hook that adds all those tags with `src` to the `dom` in the following way.

custom hook

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useScript = url => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');

        script.src = url;
        script.async = true;

        document.body.appendChild(script);

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
    }, [url]);
};

export default useScript;
```

There are lots of `js` files that are included and below is just an example of how I do it inside a functional component. I have checked and all scripts are added to the `dom`.

```js
useScript('../../../../assets/augmented3dmatrix/js/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill.js');
useScript('bower_components/visibleIf/shared/js/visibleIf.js');
useScript('bower_components/html5Forms/shared/js/EventHelpers.js');
useScript('bower_components/dialog-polyfill/dist/dialog-polyfill.js');
```

For now, I am getting errors of `undefined` in the `visibleIf.js` file.

```
src\assets\augmented3dmatrix\js\visibleIf.js
 Line 241:41:  'EventHelpers' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 488:41:  'url' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 488:47:  'config' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 492:76:  'url' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 576:31:  'ReadyState' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 580:31:  'HttpCode' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 580:60:  'HttpCode' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 672:18:  'j' is not defined                 no-undef
```

How do I add Bower packages so that the `js` file will have access to them?

IF someone knows a similar newer tool, please let me know.

Comment: That repo hasn't been updated for over 7 years, I would strongly suggest you find a similar repo, one that's maybe already in React and even better on the NPM repository.

Comment: @Keith I know that it's old, but it does what I need. I need the `matrix3d` values relative to a photo. Also, I haven't found anything better than this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<script/>` tags into the `index.html` file.

Comment: did not work, same errors trowing from `visibleIf.js`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to fork the repo and improve the code structure.
If you have several functions you need, it's better to create an npm package. There are some instructions here on https://www.section.io/engineering-education/npm-packages/